# Using SQLite with WinRT

Tags: c++, sqlite, porting, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am developing a metro ui application and I would like to use SQLite for some internal data instead of JET in order to take advantage of some already-written code.

Howerver when I try to use sqlite3_open for opening a data base, it does not work. I get an error saying a cannot open the data base.

I believe some APIs used by the SQLite cannot be used on metro style application.

Can someone help me on this? At least say me how to identify what apis should be ported?

Comment: `sqlite3_open()` should only fail if you cannot create the file that you pass it.  Do you have the appropriate permissions to create the file on disk at the location you've provided?

Comment: Check the windows event log for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work:

```
auto localAppDataParh = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
std::wstring path( localAppDataParh->Data() );
path += L"\\sample.db";
sqlite3* db;
int rc = sqlite3_open16( path.c_str(), &db);
```

> I believe some APIs used by the SQLite cannot be used on metro style application.

might work(at least on Preview Release), but not permitted. Windows App Cert Kit says:

```
   Error: This application failed the supported API check.
   API CreateFileA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. 
   API CreateFileW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. 
   API DeleteFileA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. 
    :
    :
```

Comment: It worked perfect. This functions are compiled, even though not listed on the API for metro applications. (They list CreateFile2)

Comment: Note that, aside from compiling, you'll need to also pass certification for the app to be publishable in Windows Store - and the use of those APIs will fail that certification. Dev Preview actually comes with the tool that you can use to run the test yourself, and it will also signal those functions as off-limits.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the database in the local folder. Here's a wrapper that works: http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

try this one (for UTF-8 database filenames only):

```
int ret = Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2("qq.db", out db, 1, "");
```

See [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There was just released a new WinRT SQLite3 variant, that is compatible with the Windows Store guidelines. See https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT

Comment: SQLite itself is now WinRT compliant as of v3.7.13.

Comment: yes, finally. It does not come with a WinRT component, JS wrapper/tests  though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried sqllite in WinRT, but I think it should work.  The most likely candidate is that you do not have the correct permissions to the file you are trying to open.  Check to make sure you can open the file with a simple API like fopen().  If that fails, then it is a permissions issue.  You need to have your database in a directory that your app has natural rights to.  It can't be in the user's documents folder for instance.

Comment: This is described a bit more in http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/03/winrt-storage-overview/

Comment: Hi steve, you were right. It is a permission problem as it can be seen using GetLastError. However, I did not figure out how to solve the permission problem. The App manifest is configured allright with the permissions. Even in the users document folder I can't open files.